# How do I replace the exception message with what actually caused it?

Tags: java

I am trying to print out what caused an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException inside the catch. I am only allowed to enter a single character or number, any spaces will trigger this exception. However, using the getStackTrace, I'm getting a "[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@66d3c617" error.

I've also tried the getCause(); but it returned null.

Any advice?

```
try{
    for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++)
        counts[word.charAt(i)-'A']++;
```

...

```
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        System.out.println("Not a letter " + ex.getStackTrace());
```

Comment: Any problem with `ex.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: "any spaces will trigger this exception" A number 0-9 will trigger the exception too.

Answer (score 3):

What you are probably looking for is [getMessage()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage()),

```
System.out.println("Not a letter " + ex.getMessage());
```

Calling [getStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()) returns object of type `StackTraceElement[]`, this can not be converted into a String.

To print the whole stack trace, use either:

```
ex.printStackTrace(); // print to stderr
```

or if you want to iterate the call chain, something like:

```
for ( StackTraceElement element : ex.getStackTrace() ){

    System.out.println( element.toString() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
ex.getMessage();
```

Comment: @Joe is right, this gives only a msg, but not the full stuffs needed to debug

Comment: Correct, it gave back a -33 instead of telling me a space is not a letter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to look at the stack trace, you're probably not approaching the problem in the right way.

```
for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++)
  counts[word.charAt(i)-'A']++;
```

It's quite obvious what would cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` here: a char whose value is less than `'A'`, or with `c - 'A'` greater than the array's length (*). You can detect and avoid this easily; exceptions should only be used to handle unexpected conditions.

From your comment on [spencer.sm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43667651/3788176), it seems that you want to be told what the offending character is; you won't get this from the stack trace anyway; because it doesn't know that `word.charAt(i)` isn't a letter; it just knows that some integer isn't a valid index for this array.

You should check `word.charAt(i) - 'A'` before you pass it as the array element; print the message if it is out of range.

You can do it without `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` like this, for example:

```
for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++) {
  char c = word.charAt(i);
  int index = c - 'A';
  if (index >= 0 && index < counts.length) {
    counts[index]++;
  } else {
    System.out.println(c + " is not a letter.");
    break;
  }
}
```

---

(*) Note that although your question says numbers should be accepted, a char in the range 0-9 would also trigger this exception, since `'0' < '9' < 'A'`.